# Managing Someone else's Social Media

Tags: working-from-home, clients

I've been asked if I can manage social media for someone whose business is in another province - which means I cannot easily travel to them to gather images/content/videos/etc.

How can you best manage the content for someone in this type of situation? This person sells products so would they need to constantly send me product photos and videos and all I do is post/write/strategize with them? How do you handle content in this type of situation? They want to essentially "hand-off" the responsibility of social media but I have no idea how else I would create the content. Especially since a big part of their brand is the face of the creator... which I wouldn't want to lose in their feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact  photographers that have their photos in that location, you can start with a Instagram or wherever else they post their pictures, and don’t go for that most popular ones, go for smaller photographers that are creating good content and reach out to them offering them a percentage of what you make or per photo.